# New iPhone app as update to old app, same Bundle identifier, Xcode gives error

Tags: iphone, xcode

I currently have an app in the App Store and on my device, called, for the sake of this post, MyApp1, with bundle identifier `com.myname.myapp`.

Over the last couple of weeks I have been rewriting the entire app from scratch, also adding lots of new features, as a new Xcode project alongside the old one. As far as iTunes Connect and iOS are concerned though, it should still be an update do the old (version of the) app.

During testing I had both apps running alongside each other on my device and in the simulator, with the new app using bundle identifier `com.myname.myapp2`, and everything worked fine.

But now that the app's finished, I want it to overwrite/update the old app on my device and in the simulator, to see if the code importing the data from the old app works as expected. 
So, I changed the bundle identifier of the new app in its `Info.plist` to `com.myname.myapp`, and chose `Build and Debug` in Xcode. But instead of the new app overwriting the old app while still using the same `Documents` folder, so it could import the old data, as I expected it to, I got an error.

This is what I'm doing and what happened:

- Simulator: `Reset cache`
- Xcode for MyApp1: `Clean All Targets`
- Xcode for MyApp1: `Build and Run` (using `Release` configuration)
- MyApp1: Change some `NSUserDefaults` data using the app, changes that should later be imported by MyApp2, which uses a different data model
- Xcode for MyApp1: `Stop`
- Xcode for MyApp2: `Clean All Targets`
- Xcode for MyApp2: `Build and Run` (using `Release` configuration)

What happens is the following error shows up 3 times, each time for a different classs in MyApp2's Console:

```
Unknown class [class referenced in the MyApp1 MainWindow.xib file] in Interface Builder file.
```

So it looks like for some reason not all files are overwritten, as the error is caused by the old version's `MainWindow.xib` being loaded.

(Relatively uninteresting stack frame: http://cl.ly/1F1w1J1u3t1C2U2o2D2C)

Would anyone happen to know how I can make this work, how I can have an essentially new app overwrite the old one on my device and in the simulator, so it will still use the same Documents folder?

Thanks in advance!

---

Things I already tried, as suggested by others, but didn't help:

- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting computer
- Deleting `build` folder from Xcode project folder
- `Touch`ing `MainWindow.xib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the old app's Documents folder to your Mac using the Xcode organizer window. Then remove the old app completely, install the new one. Finally restore the Documents folder backup using the Xcode organizer.

Comment: I guess that would work for testing the importing code, but I still really want to know why this (overwriting/updating MyApp1 to MyApp2 by using the same bundle identifier) doesn't work.
Also, I'm kinda scared to submit it to Apple as an update, as updating myself failed...

Comment: Xcode can be a tad stupid when it comes to overwriting files. Why don't you simulate an upgrade with an ad-hoc build installed through iTunes instead? Final users won't be using Xcode to sync their apps after all.

Comment: Oh damn, I feel so stupid for not thinking of that myself. 
Anyway, did it, and it worked up to the point where the app crashed. :P Now waiting for the Device Log in Xcode's Organizer to symbolicate, to see if I did something wrong, or if Apple did. Will upvote and accept you if it turns out the crash was my fault (which I suspect is the case).

Comment: And, as expected, the crash was my fault, and using Ad Hoc Distribution works like a charm.
Still strange though that using the Xcode overwrite/update method, not all files were overwritten...